# How to send emails via cron job usng Golang MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, golang-migrate

Hope you all doing well.
how can i using **cron job** and **cron tab(by golang connection my sql)** or anothor way using **bash script excute (file golang)**  how can i do that.

in crontab -e : set the code

> 31 17 * * *  cd /home/shanaz/Desktop/GO
> export/home/shanaz/Desktop/GO:bash sql.sh

when sql.sh code here

> go run sqll.go

Comment: create one script, which starts your script, and put this script in the crontab. Then in your crontab, you can focus on when to run the scripts, and you can test test script easily by running it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you're doing well too.

If you want to use crontab, you might want to make your shell script global by making a command calling it in your bash profile file.

If you prefer however, you can call your go script once and it would make the job alone with a goroutine processing your SQL actions when `time.Now()` has the values you want :

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6